# Why I am getting wrong params using change streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a feature of the app that will draw a chart by clicking the symbol from the list (ex: MSFT - Microsoft, AAPL - Apple, GOOG - Google). The symbol will be sent by the route `router.get('/app/:symbol', getWebApi);` as a parameter that will be used to draw and update the chart data from the database.

Database is being updated in a certain interval and observed by `MongoDB - change streams` to push data to front-end `on('change')`. Here is my problem. When I click first time on `MSFT` - `req.parms.symbol: MSFT` everything is working as it should be. On second click `AAPL` - `req.parms.symbol: AAPL` first `console.log()` gives me a correct parameter of the symbol but as soon as it hits `on('change')` it will `console.log()` the symbol `MSFT` from the first click and alternate with `AAPL` which is the current parameter.

Same thing will happen on the third click `GOOG`. So I am confused why I am getting parameters that were called on previous clicks. If you have any ideas I would appreciate it. Thank you!

**upd:** When you open up a change stream, it stays open even after the request handler is done. That explains why I am  getting multiple `on('change')` events when I make multiple API requests.

**controller - stock.js**

```
exports.getWebApi = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { symbol } = req.params;

    console.log('on entry req.params.symbol: ', symbol);
    console.log(typeof symbol);

    const apiKeyAlpha = process.env.API_KEY_ALPHAVANTAGE;

    const urlCompact = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=${symbol}&outputsize=compact&apikey=${apiKeyAlpha}`;

    const webApiData = await Db.fetchWebApiStock(urlCompact);
    await Db.creatUpdateStock(symbol, webApiData);

    const db = mongoose.connection;
    const taskCollection = db.collection('stocks');
    const pipeline = [
      {
        $match: {
          'ns.db': 'myapp',
          'ns.coll': 'stocks',
          'fullDocument.symbol': symbol,
        },
      },
    ];

    const options = { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' };
    const changeStream = taskCollection.watch(pipeline, options);

    changeStream.on('change', change => {
      console.log('req.params.symbol in change: ', symbol);

      const { fullDocument } = change;

      const logData = fullDocument.data.map(item => ({
        date: parseFloat(item.date),
        open: parseFloat(item.open),
        high: parseFloat(item.high),
        low: parseFloat(item.low),
        close: parseFloat(item.close),
        volume: parseInt(item.volume),
      }));

      // pusher.trigger(channel, 'AnyEvent', {
      //   chartData: logData,
      //   symbol: fullDocument.symbol,
      // });

    });

    res.send(webApiData);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log('getWebApi error:', ex);
  }
};
```

**on first click**

```
GET /stock/chart/MSFT 304 22.401 ms - -
GET /JS/chart.js 304 0.282 ms - -
GET /JS/chartWebSearch.js 304 0.286 ms - -
on entry req.parms.symbol:  MSFT
string
GET /stock/app/MSFT 304 896.008 ms - -
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
GET /stock/updatedb 304 908.734 ms - -
```

**on second click**

```
GET /stock/chart/AAPL 304 4.494 ms - -
GET /JS/chart.js 304 0.361 ms - -
GET /JS/chartWebSearch.js 304 0.354 ms - -
on entry req.parms.symbol:  AAPL
string
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
GET /stock/app/AAPL 304 558.962 ms - -
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  AAPL
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  AAPL
req.params.symbol in change:  AAPL
req.params.symbol in change:  AAPL
req.params.symbol in change:  AAPL
req.params.symbol in change:  AAPL
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
GET /stock/updatedb 304 893.851 ms - -
```

**on third click**

```
GET /stock/chart/GOOG 304 5.002 ms - -
GET /JS/chart.js 304 0.296 ms - -
GET /JS/chartWebSearch.js 304 0.451 ms - -
on entry req.parms.symbol:  GOOG
string
req.params.symbol in change:  AAPL
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  AAPL
GET /stock/app/GOOG 304 741.986 ms - -
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  GOOG
req.params.symbol in change:  AAPL
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  GOOG
req.params.symbol in change:  GOOG
req.params.symbol in change:  GOOG
req.params.symbol in change:  AAPL
req.params.symbol in change:  AAPL
req.params.symbol in change:  AAPL
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  GOOG
req.params.symbol in change:  GOOG
req.params.symbol in change:  AAPL
req.params.symbol in change:  AAPL
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
req.params.symbol in change:  MSFT
GET /stock/updatedb 304 820.259 ms - -
```

Comment: Please post text as text, not images of text.

Comment: You're continually adding new `change` handlers.

Comment: @DaveNewton is not the `change` handler is killed when I change the web page ?

Comment: @DaveNewton I am confused. How does it work?

Comment: There's no navigation away from the pager here--if the page reloads, yes, all current js code would go away. If you don't hesitate away you're adding a handler with a closure on each getWebApi execution, which would explain precisely what you're seeing.

Comment: @DaveNewton What does it mean ? --- If you don't hesitate away---

Comment: It means the phone auto-corrected "navigate" to "hesitate".